# Transaction spanning multiple WARs

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, transactions, jta

I have two WARs running on the same tomcat server, both using Spring transactions and both writing to the same database. They communicate with each other through REST calls.

Now I have a business process that starts from `foo.war`, which calls `bar.war`, then returns back to `foo.war`. Both of them write to the same database, but they currently are not part of one transaction, so if `foo.war` fails to commit, `bar.war` doesn't rollback.

How can I solve this problem without integrating one war into the other?

I though a standalone JTA implementation might work, but since they are different applications, I'm not sure if it will.

Comment: how is the business process in foo.war calling bar.war? Is it through REST?

Comment: Yes. I thought I indicated that. Foo and Bar communicate through rest calls.

Comment: @user2953113 yes, looks ugly. Not worth the try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your use case is well suited for transaction based on TCC architecture. Pls find below links for details on the architecture :-
a) [Link-1](http://www.atomikos.com/Publications/TransactionsForTheRestOfUs)
b) [Link-2](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Transactions-HTTP-REST)

Comment: I cannot accept this solution, since it requires manual cleanup on an unsuccessful transaction. I prefer something that would provide rollback transparently, just as a conventional database does.

Comment: TCC does not require manual cleanup after an unsuccessful transaction. It does allow for application-specific compensation handling which makes it so powerful. If your application foo/bar requires classical rollback then maybe REST is not the right architecture in the first place.